# Create Entity from existing Entity based on a property value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have the below example of a rather generic `Item` Entity that has been generated using Database First, the `ADO.Net Entity Data Model` in Visual Studio 2012 and Entity Framework 5 creating a .edmx file with a template that generated the classes for me.

I am trying to find out if it is possible to generate a new Entity without making database changes, so that I have a new Entity based on the `ItemType`. **I know I can do this using Linq to Entities but I am interested to know if this is possible in the model Context.**

As an example:
An `ItemType` in the database might have a value of `{1, "Fabric"}` and I would like to create a new Entity called `FabricItem` based on the `Item` class.. as you can see the `ColourId` and `RangeId` are nullable as some of the subclasses of `Item` I expect not to use these properties i.e. some are optional.

Is it also possible in when creating these new Entities... to remove/disable some properties, such as not allowing a `ColourId` at all?

```
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.ItemToItems = new HashSet<ItemToItem>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ColourId { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RangeId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual Range Range { get; set; }
    public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemToItem> ItemToItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemToItem> ItemToItems1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemImage> ItemImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemToItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string RelatedItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Range
{
    public Range()
    {
        this.Items= new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemType
{
    public ItemType()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Colour
{
    public Colour()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hex { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public int ImageTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ImageType ImageType { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public partial class ImageType
{
    public ImageType()
    {
        this.ItemImages = new HashSet<ItemImage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemImage> ItemImages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can map multiple entities to 1 table (or vice versa) with a discriminator column but your example does not match that. Is the Db really fixed?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for that comment, I wasn't aware of the discriminator column and after searching for that I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591617 and the section on `Table-Per-Hierarchy` seems the same as what I am doing, but my situation might be made more difficult due to the Item to Item relationship? Why do you feel this example does not match? at first look it seems to be the same. My DB is not completely fixed but I would prefer not to break up the tables by their types.

Comment: Also based on now knowing what to look for, I found this very useful post: http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/ and I can already see my example is made more complicated due to the relationships.. I have updated my example code slightly because I took some bits out to keep the example simple.

Comment: A problem I am also having is that I know `Range` can be moved to one of my sub classes  but my database has a foreign key constraint between `Item` and `Range` and I am not sure if it is a good idea to move this property at all.